# Are all conversions to Orthodox Judaism (Haredi, Hasidic and Modern) recognized in Israel?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, eretz-yisrael, orthodox

I am ready to convert to Judaism, but I am curious about how conversions performed under Orthodox auspices are perceived in Israel. For example, I understand that the current Israeli government is run by the Haredi, or "Ultra-Orthodox," and that they will only grant privileges such as the right to marriage or burial within the Jewish nation to those who have undergone conversions through recognized/approved batei din, such as the RCA. However, what exactly constitutes an "Orthodox Conversion?" Aside from being done in accordance with halacha, are all conversions accepted, whether they are Modern Orthodox, Haredi or Hasidic?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Words! May you be successful in your endeavours!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: @Words_of_Wisdom This is a very hot topic at the moment in Israel. The Chief Rabbinate have issued a list restricting the number of rabbis abroad whom they recognize for conversions. This has excluded rabbis who are regarded as orthodox in their own communities. The current Israeli government is not run by haredim (although they have strong influence), and in any case the matter rests with the Chief Rabbinate, not the government. If you are sure you want to convert, and then make Aliyah, be sure that your conversion will be recognized here by using an "authorized" rabbi.

Comment: Complicated question, but what is fairly clear is that if they feel that the Rabbi/Beit Din in question cannot be relied upon they will not recognise it. As to why that might include some Orthodox Rabbis can vary - some are clearly anything but orthodox, whilst others clearly are, just the Chief Rabbinate feel their conversions are not conducted correctly. I don't add this as an answer because it is at best partial.

Comment: @Words_of_Wisdom If you are going to convert, be *very, very, very* careful about with whom you do it. Every rabbi will tell you that his conversion is 100% kosher and will effectively be accepted in Israel; however, this is not true. I'd highly recommend cross-checking several published lists for the rabbi's name (ITIM's list alone is not 100% reliable) ... start with this https://www.haaretz.co.il/st/inter/Hheb/images/rabanim1.pdf

Comment: @Words_of_Wisdom In my opinion -- and this is advice I'd give to any prospective convert -- your main, if not only, criterion in selecting a beis din should be whether the conversion will be considered legit by Israel

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: ... And yes, AFAIK there are chareidi, modern orthodox, and chassidish batei din on the list (though very rarely all three options in the same city)

Comment: Would you happen to know which branch of Orthodoxy the Rabbinical Council of America consists of?

Comment: @Words_of_Wisdom, you might be interested in [this](http://www.itim.org.il/en/recognized-rabbinical-courts-for-conversion/) list of Betei Dinim recognized by the State of Israel for valid conversions worldwide.

Comment: @ezra Thank you for directing me toward this list! I have actually perused it before, but in never hurts to take another look!

Comment: @Words_of_Wisdom - May Hashem Yisborach guide you through your conversion and help you to succeed, if it is His Will that you should.